# Hibernate trying to persist the wrong object

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm experiencing a problem in one of the unit test classes in my Spring Boot project which I just cannot explain.  Here are my test methods:

```
// This test creates a record with callback id 5a6775ab4b0af8693ba97c5b
@Test
public void testCreate() throws Exception {
    Callback callback = fixtures.getCallback(TestFixtureFactory.EMAILS_SUCCESS);
    boolean created = createCallbackDao.createCallback(callback);
    assertThat(created).as("Check create callback succeeded").isTrue();
}

// This test creates a record with callback id 5a6775ab4b0af8693ba97c5x and then tries to create it again,
// which is expected to fail with a unique constraint violation.
@Test
public void testAlreadyExists() throws Exception {
    Callback callbackA = fixtures.getCallback(TestFixtureFactory.EMAILS_DUPLICATE);
    boolean a = createCallbackDao.createCallback(callbackA);
    assertThat(a).as("Check first create callback succeeded").isTrue();
    assertThatExceptionOfType(ConstraintViolationException.class).isThrownBy(() -> {
        Callback callbackB = fixtures.getCallback(TestFixtureFactory.EMAILS_DUPLICATE);
        boolean b = createCallbackDao.createCallback(callbackB);
    });
}
```

What happens is that the testAlreadyExists() test is executed first and passes as expected but the testCreate(), which is executed second, fails with a unique constraint violation.

I have tried running each test separately and both pass, as expected, when doing this.

Here is the log output from testCreate() when running both tests:

```
2018-03-19 13:00:21.347  INFO 10646 --- [           main] c.y.p.apicallback.dao.impl.CallbackDao   : Create callback for callback id = 5a6775ab4b0af8693ba97c5b
2018-03-19 13:00:21.347  INFO 10646 --- [           main] c.y.p.apicallback.dao.impl.CallbackDao   : Callback=Callback [id=13, callbackId=5a6775ab4b0af8693ba97c5b, ...]
2018-03-19 13:00:21.349 DEBUG 10646 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into api_callback (created, last_modified, callback_id, last_update, message, request_source, state, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into api_callback (created, last_modified, callback_id, last_update, message, request_source, state, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2018-03-19 13:00:21.350 TRACE 10646 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Mon Mar 19 13:00:21 GMT 2018]
2018-03-19 13:00:21.350 TRACE 10646 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2018-03-19 13:00:21.311]
2018-03-19 13:00:21.350 TRACE 10646 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [5a6775ab4b0af8693ba97c5x]
2018-03-19 13:00:21.350 TRACE 10646 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Tue Jan 23 17:49:31 GMT 2018]
2018-03-19 13:00:21.350 TRACE 10646 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [Send email request completed.]
2018-03-19 13:00:21.350 TRACE 10646 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [8] as [BIGINT] - [7]
2018-03-19 13:00:21.350  WARN 10646 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 23505, SQLState: 23505
2018-03-19 13:00:21.351 ERROR 10646 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unique index or primary key violation: "API_CALLBACK_U1_INDEX_4 ON API_CALLBACK(CALLBACK_ID) VALUES ('5a6775ab4b0af8693ba97c5x', 1)"; SQL statement:
insert into api_callback (created, last_modified, callback_id, last_update, message, request_source, state, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23505-196]
2018-03-19 13:00:21.351  INFO 10646 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2018-03-19 13:00:21.351 ERROR 10646 --- [           main] c.y.p.apicallback.dao.impl.CallbackDao   : Error creating Callback, time(ms)=4!

org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at   org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
```

Here is the code for the DAO method being called:

```
@Override
public boolean createCallback(Callback callback) throws Exception {
    LOG.info("Create callback for callback id = {}", callback.getCallbackId());
    Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.createStarted();
    Session session = null;
    Transaction txn = null;
    try {
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        txn = session.getTransaction();
        LOG.info("Callback={}", callback);
        session.persist(callback);
        session.flush();
        txn.commit();
        LOG.info("CallbackDao.createCallback: company={}, callbackId={}, id={}, time(ms)={}",
                callback.getRequest().getUser(), callback.getCallbackId(), callback.getId(), timer.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error(String.format("Error creating Callback, time(ms)=%d!", timer.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)), e);
        if (txn.getStatus() == TransactionStatus.ACTIVE || txn.getStatus() == TransactionStatus.MARKED_ROLLBACK) {
            txn.rollback();
        }
        throw e;
    }
}
```

The API_CALLBACK table has a generated primary key value (ID) and a unique index on the CALLBACK_ID column.  The ID value is derived from a database sequence prior to calling the DAO method to persist the record.

The problem is that the callback record that should be inserted into the database is the one that is logged as follows:

```
2018-03-19 13:00:21.347  INFO 10646 --- [           main] c.y.p.apicallback.dao.impl.CallbackDao   : Callback=Callback [id=13, callbackId=5a6775ab4b0af8693ba97c5b, ...]
```

However, according to the bind variables logged by Hibernate it is in fact trying to insert a record with different id and callback id values:

```
2018-03-19 13:00:21.350 TRACE 10646 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [5a6775ab4b0af8693ba97c5x] (should be 5a6775ab4b0af8693ba97c5b)
2018-03-19 13:00:21.350 TRACE 10646 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [8] as [BIGINT] - [7] (should be 13)
```

The record with ID 7 and Callback Id 5a6775ab4b0af8693ba97c5x was inserted into the local (H2) database during the testAlreadyExists() test.

I can't figure out why the DAO class is showing that it is working with one object instance but Hibernate is trying to persist a different one.  Can anyone help?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem stems from a duplicate record that is not expected to be there? If this is the case, is your test class transactional?

Comment: Your understanding is correct.  The test class was not transactional but adding that annotation to it resolved the problem.  A thousand thank yous!

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to [kirinya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6756475/kirinya) (see comment above) the solution is to make the test class transactional using the annotation `javax.transaction.Transactional`.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { TestDatabaseConfiguration.class })
@Transactional
public class TestCreateCallbackDao {
...
}
```